# Issues on adding Packages in Visual Studio 2015 through Package.config

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, package-managers, nuget-package-restore

I tried to add the package by simply appending with appropriate xml tag in the package.config and I tried to build the project but its not adding the reference in the project.

The newly added package is

```
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
```

My Existing `package.config` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Moq" version="4.7.25" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="XtraLib.Common" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

My update version of the `package.config` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Moq" version="4.7.25" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="XtraLib.Common" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

While on building the project is not adding the reference. Kindly assist me how to do this. Because I get information and I will add it here instead of manual installation.

> Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Any update for this issue? Could you get any useful info from the answer? If not, let me know the latest info about this question for free.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT - No, its not updating the package.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a sample for this question, you can check if it help you. If not, could you share us the detail result after using below method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> While on building the project is not adding the reference. Kindly assist me how to do this. Because I get information and I will add it here instead of manual installation.

That because **NuGet Restore only restores files in the packages directory (\packages folder ), but does not restore files inside your project or otherwise modify your project.**

You should use the NuGet command line in the Package Manager Console after you **first build**:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

to force reinstall the package references into project.

You can refer to the [similar issue on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775876/nuget-packages-are-there-but-missing-references/42778916#42778916) for detail info.

**Note**: You should make sure the checkboxes of "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio" are checked(Tools->Option->NuGet Package Manager->General).

[image]

**Update:**
I have created a sample for this question, you can refer to below for more detail:

[image]

Note: After the command `Update-Package -reinstall`, the targetFramework of all package will change to `net461`(Because you are using Visual Studio 2015 Framework 4.6.1).

Comment: @Mastero , I have update my answer more detail, you can check if it help you. If not, please let me know for free, I will keep follow.