# All MS VS References broken after project moved

Tags: windows, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

Exactly as asked in [Moved project, now references are broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384476/) -- having *moved a project to another folder, now all of my references are broken*, however, the answer there is incorrect, as we can see that it is not only the NuGet Packages are broken, but all of them, even including `System`, `Microsoft.CSharp`, etc:

[image]

How to properly fix it? 
This is

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.3.5
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.3.5+26730.16
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038
```

**UPDATE:**

Find a case that is even don't need moving anything -- I tried to include a project from another solution, whose references are perfectly fine within that solution, but all are broken when included in my new solution, despite the fact that all the references, accessible (specified in the .csproj file) via *relative paths* or no path at all:

```
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
<Reference Include="System.Management" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
<Reference Include="WebDriver, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.3.4.0\lib\net40\WebDriver.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="WebDriver.Support, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\packages\Selenium.Support.3.4.0\lib\net40\WebDriver.Support.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Is this a .NET Core project or a .NET Framework project?

Comment: @Dai, I selected the "Class Library (.NET Framework)" when creating it.