# Visual Studio references not resolved until clicked on

Tags: visual-studio, reference, nuget, nuget-package-restore

References (specifically from internal nuget server) seem to be unresolved after using restore nuget packages. The project builds fine but anything that uses these references show as errors in the code until you manually expand references and click it (shows a warning on the reference, when clicked it resolves and removes warning).

Is there an easy way to auto resolve them without going through every project and clicking the refrerence manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to auto resolve them without going through every project and clicking the refrerence manually?

Please try to use the NuGet command line in the Package Manager Console:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

to force reinstall the package references into project.

NuGet Restore only restores files in the packages directory (\packages folder ), but does not restore files inside your project or otherwise modify your project.

Check the [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775876/nuget-packages-are-there-but-missing-references/42778916#42778916) for some more details.