# How reproduce VS2017 Package Manager command "Update-Package -reinstall" with Nuget CLI

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, teamcity, package-managers, nuspec

I've tried with Nuget Update, Nuget restore, but they are actually not the same and here's why:

I've created a Nuget pkg only to distribute an executable file. When I install the Nuget the executable is added to my project so I can reference it and run it within my application.

Now, I don't want that every developer has to install the Nuget to have the executable in their project, but I just want the .exe to be added when the project is built. And of course, the reference to the package in the config file is present.

If I run `Update-Package -Id -reinstall`(using the Package Manager of VS) a folder with the .exe is added to the project root, but if I do `nuget update` or `nuget restore` (using the nuget CLI) it only re-add the .exe into the packages folder.

The reason why I need to run the nuget CLI is because I'm using TeamCity and I want to add the .exe when the automatic build runs.

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17733307/7225096 This is old question but imho nothing changed since nuget 2.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How reproduce VS2017 Package Manager command “Update-Package -reinstall” with Nuget CLI

I am afraid you can NOT do such things with NuGet CLI. That because **NuGet CLI does not modify a project file or packages.config**. When we modify the project file, we need to do it by [NuGet API in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/nuget-api-in-visual-studio), but only package manager console can provide access to visual studio objects:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1512

That is the reason why I said the easiest way is using the command line `Update-Package -Id -reinstall` in your [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390329/how-install-nuget-package-when-building-project-in-visual-studio/51396358#51396358). Then I also gave you another way to resolve this issue from the root cause, using `.targets` file to copy the executable file to the the project root, please check my update answer.

Of course, there is another simple idea to resolve this issue, just add a **pre-build event** in your project to copy the executable file to the the project root:

```
xcopy  /Y "$(SolutionDir)packages\MyToolPackage.1.0.0\Tools\wkhtmltopdf.exe" "$(ProjectDir)"
```

Hope this helps.