# asp.net team project show assembly reference missing and others error

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

I have start working on team project but when i map project to my work space it gives me multiple errors. First the tell me missing references. But this project is working fine on other system of group member.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding solution.

Comment: yes but same error appear

Comment: Read the warnings. Probably some package paths are messed up.

Comment: go to Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager and make sure that "Allow NuGet download missing packages" is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below items to fix the issue:

- Run below command in the **Package Manager Console** to reinstall the
  packages: (Reference this thread :[Nuget Packages are there but missing References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775876/nuget-packages-are-there-but-missing-references))

  `Update-Package -reinstall`
- Navigate to Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager

  1. First make sure that "`Allow NuGet to download missing packages`"
     and "`Atuomatically check for missing packages during build in
     Visual Studio`" are checked.
  2. Then make sure that the "`package.config`" file contains the all the
     references you need for your project.
  3. To force Nuget to download all the libraries again, delete the
     "`packages`" folder in the root path of your solution.
  4. Rebuild your solution.
  5. Now Nuget should download all the packages again.

[image]