# How to get NuGet packages to restore correctly for an existing project added from another solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have two Visual Studio 2019 solutions, A and B, with both containing several projects. Solution A includes one of the projects from solution B, *ProjectB*, which was added to A as an existing project. This project uses several NuGet dependencies. Obviously, NuGet packages are not under source control. When a user freshly checks out the solutions from source control, here's what happens:

1. If solution B is opened and built first, *ProjectB*'s NuGet dependencies get restored as expected, and the project builds successfully.
2. If solution A is opened and built after 1., everything gets built successfully. However, if step 1 is omitted, *ProjectB* fails to build within the scope of solution A because its referenced dependencies don't get recreated in the original path, despite NuGet having installed all the dependencies in A's `packages` folder. This results in plenty of "The referenced component could not be found" error messages, and a situation equivalent to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775876/nuget-packages-are-there-but-missing-references).

Simply cleaning the NuGet cache doesn't help. The only thing that seems to resolve the issue is to call

```
Update-Package -reinstall -ProjectName ProjectB
```

from the solution A's Package Manager Console prior to triggering a (re)build.

I wanted to automate this by including the `Update-Package` command in a pre-build event, but apparently Package Manager Console is not accessible there, and I'd like to avoid installing any other software.

Is there a way to correctly get all project dependencies restored in such case, so that the entire solution A would build from scratch automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you can use **PackageReference** format inside a project instead of *packages* folder, and doing so resolves the original issue directly without any extra action needed. So the most elegant solution is to [migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference): right-click on the problematic project's *References* in solution explorer, then click `Migrate packages.config to PackageReference` in the context menu. From now on, NuGet dependencies will resolve correctly when a project is included in another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to add a Nuget.Config file as a Solution Item to each solution and add the "respositoryPath" config key to the file so the two solutions are resolving Nuget package references to the same folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
     <add key="repositoryPath" value="../../Nuget/packages" />
  <config>
</configuration>
```

Obviously, you'll want to adjust the repositoryPath value for each Nuget.Config file so the same path is used for both solution (if Solution A is one folder lower in the file structure than Solution B, you'll need to add another `../` to the path).

After you add the Nuget.Config file to each solution, you need to close/re-open each solution and then run `Update-Package -reinstall` to ensure the reference paths are updated in each project file.