# Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web and packages.config

Tags: c#, nuget, csproj, packages.config

I have a web project that I'm trying to convert to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web. When I make the change to the .csproj file, though, it seems to force it to be interpreted as a `<PackageReference>`-based project. Of course, `<PackageReference>` isn't supported in web projects, because it doesn't support persisting the results of installing a package. Web projects *must* use `packages.config` in order to support NuGet packages that inject static content into the site's space (such as NewRelic). But, after switching to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, the build system seems absolutely stuck on the project being `<PackageReference>`-based. How do I resolve this? Surely the very existence of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` implies that it is possible to use `packages.config` with an SDK project. But, even if I set `<RestoreProjectStyle>Packages.config</RestoreProjectStyle>`, it still thinks the project is `<PackageReference>`-based. I've seen advice to try running `Update-Package -Reinstall` after clearing out `obj`, `bin` and `.vs`, but nothing I've tried has convinced it that this is *not* a `<PackageReference>`-based project:

[image: The -Reinstall parameter does not apply to PackageReference based projects]

In Visual Studio, all of the NuGet-inserted references are lumped in with other references under Dependencies\Assemblies, and the "Installed" tab of the NuGet Package Manager is empty.

What do I do?

Comment: _Surely the very existence of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web implies that it is possible to use packages.config with an SDK project._ → could you please clarify what brings you to this assumption?

Comment: @mu88 The fact that they took the time to create an entire SDK just for web projects when web projects _must_ use packages.config.

Comment: @mu88 If you open a web project, right-click on its packages.config file and select "Migrate packages.config to PackageReference", you get a notice that says, "Operation failed - Project is not eligible for migration". The system recognizes that web projects must use packages.config. Based on that, it is only logical that they wouldn't make Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web _if it couldn't be used_.

Comment: `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` is meant to be used for ASP.NET Core and all the ASP.NET Core templates and projects I know use `PackageReference`, not `packages.config` - but maybe you find a counterexample 

Comment: Oh? But then how do they use things like NewRelic, that want to dump a bunch of static content into the project as part of package installation??

Comment: I don't know NewRelic, but usually these kind of things are done via `contentFiles` ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files))