# HtmlParser. Failed to load file or assembly

Tags: c#, anglesharp

**Bug Report**

```
System.TypeInitializationException  
  HResult = 0x80131534  
  Message = Initializer type "AngleSharp.Configuration" threw an exception.  
  Source = AngleSharp  
  Stack trace:  
   in AngleSharp.Configuration.get_Default ()  
   in AngleSharp.BrowsingContext.NewFrom [TService] (TService instance)  
   in AngleSharp.Html.Parser.HtmlParser..ctor ()  
   in rsh.Parser_test..ctor () in Z: \ vs \ csharp \ prb \ rsh \ rsh \ Parser_test.cs: line 19  
   in rsh.Form1..ctor () in Z: \ vs \ csharp \ prb \ rsh \ rsh \ Form1.cs: line 18  
   in rsh.Program.Main () in Z: \ vs \ csharp \ prb \ rsh \ rsh \ Program.cs: line 19  

Internal exception 1:  
FileNotFoundException: Failed to load file or assembly  
"System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, Version = 4.0.2.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a" or one of their dependencies. Cannot find the specified file.
```

**Can you reproduce the problem in a MWE?**
no

**Are you running the latest version of AngleSharp?**
Version - 0.10.1

**Did you check the FAQs to see if that helps you?**
used google search. did not help

**Are you reporting to the correct repository? (there are multiple AngleSharp libraries, e.g., AngleSharp.Css for CSS support)**
see screen

**Did you perform a search in the issues?**
Searched for phrase: "Failed to load file or assembly"

**Description**
I get the error "Failed to load file or assembly" during application launch

**Steps to Reproduce**
Error occurs when starting the application

**Environment details: [OS, .NET Runtime, ...]**
Win 7x64.
VS - 2017
.NET Framework 4.6.1

**Code**

```
using AngleSharp.Html.Parser;

namespace rsh
{
    class Parser_test
    {
        HtmlParser domParser;

        public Parser_test()
        {
            domParser = new HtmlParser();
        }

    }
}
```

I installed:
 "System.Text.Encoding.CodePages".
Error remained.
Additional reasoning - [link](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/746)
**Pic.1** 
[image]

**Pic.2** 
[image]

**Pic.3** 
[image]

**Pic.4** 
[image]

**Update-1**
Based on - [stackoverflow.com/a/40775352/10530657](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40775352/10530657)
Completed
`Update-Package -reinstall`.
Closed, opened *Visual Studio*.
Opened in *Visual Studio 2015*.

No result.

**Update-2**
Installed "AngleSharp - 0.9.11".
The error is gone.

**Update-3**
Installed - `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages`
**Pic.5**
[image]

**Update-4**
Collected the console project,
The project gives an error.
Maybe someone will have the opportunity to check on their side.
Or send me a project that works.
Maybe this will help identify the cause of the error.

The project is made on the basis of documentation "AngleSharp"- [documentation . link](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Documentation)
Link to the project - [link](https://yadi.sk/d/LpyrKrJfQ0Sfcg)

**Question**
How to make the error not appear in "AngleSharp - 0.10.01"?

Comment: Even though System.Text.Encoding.CodePages is included as a NuGet package it doesn't appear to be referenced/included by the project. Try adding a reference to the project references

Comment: @phuzi `Try adding a reference to the project references` - how to do it.
I can not understand.
Could you describe in more detail how to do this?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40775352/592958

Comment: @phuzi updated question

Comment: @phuzi `updated-2` question

Comment: I just created a new console application, installed the AngleSharp package (0.10.1) and copy/pasted the "First Steps" code from [this page](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Documentation).  I got the same exception as you, so I installed the `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` package and the application built and ran with no issues.  You said you installed that last package in your project, but can you see it in your project references?

Comment: @Archer Updated the question. `Update-3`
Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes - that's fine and should work.  I can't read anything other than the code, I'm afraid, so I can't be much help if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Archer I understood you.
I understood you correctly, because the text in the picture is not in English, then you have no opportunity to help?
Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  Also, it's difficult to help because we appear to have done the same thing and it works for me but not for you.  (By the way, HTH means "Hope that helps")

Comment: @Archer I thought...
Maybe you will not be difficult, the project that works for you, put on file sharing. I will try to open it at home.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't do that.  Here are the steps.  1) Create a new console application (.Net 4.6.1).  Copy and paste the code from `Main()` in "First Steps" example on [this linked page](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Documentation).  Open Nuget Package Manager and add the package AngleSharp (v0.10.1), then add the package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages (v4.5.1).  That's it - it should build and run.

Comment: @Archer Does not work.
The project attached to the question just in case. (`Update-4`  )

Probably while they will work with AngleSharp - 9.

Comment: I can't help you then.  I can only think you have an environment issue (problem with your Visual Studio or .Net installation).  Good luck resolving your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i had the same  problem

your project > rightClick > manage nuget packages >

search : `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages`
install that .

---

**long:**

anglesharp  nuget  details:

> .net framework  4.6  requires "System.Text.Encoding.CodePages".

just installing **angleSharp, doesn't install  the required package automatically**. you need  to install from  nuget package manager.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same exception, and it took me a few minutes to realize....

If you have AngleSharp in a class library, you also need to install it in whatever is consuming the class library.

Oops.