# Could not load file or assembly Nuget packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have an ASP.Net project which has several sub projects referenced.

I decided today to update some of my nuget packages to have newer versions, what a mistake it was.

Now when I try to debug my app I get this exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.'
>
> InnerException : FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

It seems like it's looking to load 6.0.0.0 which is not referenced by any of my subprojects, maybe one of the other nugetpackages ?

I've followed several questions here to perform different operations including:
- Deleting packages folder in Windows Explorer
- Reinstalling the Newtonsoft.Json package
- Clearing the cache of the package in the settings of VS
- Restoring the packages
- Cleaning my solution
- Restarting VS

I'm using VS 2017 community.

I tried to update several other packages to see if it could be linked and I got many new exceptions so I just decided to stop the mess and rollback everything.

But the problem is still here after the rollback so i'm really unsure about what I should do now.

Links I've checked before: [Nuget package installed but references not resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663511/nuget-package-installed-but-references-not-resolved)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore-troubleshooting

Comment: Have you checked Newtonsoft.Json version in each of project's packages.config file?

Comment: Delete "packages" folder completely from the solution root. Check nuget packages on a solution level ("Manage Nuget packages for Solution..."), maybe you have different versions of the same package installed for different projects. Uninstall remaining packages manually. Reinstall them from the repository.

Comment: Thank you for your messages. However it didn't work. I've checked and they all have the same Newtonsoft.Json version (10.0.3). Maybe an other package is using an old version?

Comment: The innerexception is looking for the version 6.0.0 for some reason.