# Xamarin can not resolve reference even if this is installed

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion

im new at this plataaform and i was wondering to work with third party controls,-because i think they look great with less effort-,my problem begin when i start to compile de solution,i get the following error :

> Can not resolve reference: Xamarin.Android.Support.Interpolator, referenced by Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.Android. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Interpolator, or remove the reference to Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.Android.learningXamarinExtraUI.Android

That happens even after install the package,i had read similar questions here and tried the solutions proposed :( and all of  that i had tried did not worked

[image]

Solutions proposed that i tried: 
  -[Nuget package installed but references not resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663511/nuget-package-installed-but-) 
   references-not-resolved
  -[Nuget Packages are there but missing References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775876/nuget-packages-are-there-but-) 
   missing-references/42778916

Comment: Try clean the project and rebuilt it.

Comment: @Jaymin already did that,not worked;thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can able to reproduce the report issue “`Can not resolve reference: Xamarin.Android.Support.Interpolator, referenced by Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.Android. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Interpolator, or remove the reference to Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.Android.learningXamarinExtraUI.Android`”.

Your requirement can be achieved by changing the Target FrameWork version as 9.0 on Android project to resolve this.

[image: Android Api Target Version]

Note: This cause due to Xamarin Forms V3.6 and its support libraries does match to Android Api version.

Please revert us, if you still facing this issue at your end.

Regards,

Karthik Raja

Comment: thanks, just had the same issue today when updating syncfusion from 17.2 to 17.3