# Xamarin.Forms install error message runaround

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a new Xamarin.Forms project and I am trying to upgrade the Xamarin.Forms Nuget package from 3.6 to v4.3. When I try to install a newer version I get a runaround of error messages that goes in circles. Here's how it goes:

- Right click on solution >Manage Nuget Packages
- Installed Tab >Xamarin.Forms. Shows v3.6 installed in all projects (main/shared project, Android, UWP)
- Select v4.3 and install upgrade to all projects
- Error: Error NU1107  Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.3 directly to project HPlusSports.Android to resolve this issue.
- I search for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, select v28.0.0.3 and install it directly into my Android project.
- Error: Error NU1107  Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations 28.0.0.3 directly to project HPlusSports.Android to resolve this issue.
- I search for Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations, select v28.0.0.3 and install it directly into my Android project.
- Error: Error NU1107  Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations 28.0.0.3 directly to project HPlusSports.Android to resolve this issue.

So I follow the instructions in the error messages but the error messages just go in circles. No matter what I try to install there is no resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only updating *Xamarin Forms Nuget Package* will occur *other Nuget Package conflict* with it.

Have a try with follow steps :

- Right click project solution
- Click **Manage Nuget Package for Solution**
- Go to **Updates** view
- Select All Packages
- Last click **Update** button

Such as follow screenshot :

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence but your instructions are clear. I followed them and the previous errors went away. Unfortunately on trying to build the project there was a new error saying I needed to increase the Android target framework to 9.0. So I did that. That error went away but then there were 3 new errors about "Attribute 'closeIcon'" "icon" and "icon tint" already defined.

Comment: I did a search the "Attribute icon already defined" error and was able to resolve it by changing the Android build tools to v29. Turns out the Android build tools I had installed was an old obsolete version. I tried to build and it's finally working! Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: @technoman23 Glad sovled that ! Thanks for marking it and I have edited answer to be more clear . Your comment will also be very helpful for others to solve this problem  :-) .

Answer (score 0):

To this problem, open your android project .csproj file by notepad.

Add the package into PackageReference directly. Save it and open the solution again.

Example:

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.4.0.991864" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.VersionedParcelable">
  <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Interpolator">
  <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView">
  <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment">
  <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI">
  <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils">
  <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations">
  <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.CursorAdapter">
  <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Collections">
  <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat">
  <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design">
  <Version>28.0.0.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

Comment: OK I tried it, I added the Xamarin.Forms reference in the file via notepad. When I reopen the project in Visual Studio I get the error message again about Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.3 directly into Android project

Comment: Please try to update the version of Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat and it's dependencies library to 28.0.0.3

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/166267/version-conflict-detected-for-xamarin-android-support-compat

Similar issue for your information

Comment: Ok I tried it. Gives the following error message now: Error NU1107 Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations 28.0.0.3 directly to project HPlusSports.Android to resolve this issue.

Comment: Adding all these kinds of libraries to your project will solve it. or you can just copy mine which might have some redundant.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this procedure.** [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52964634/8490598)

1. Update-package
2. Update-Package -reinstall
3. Restart visual studio.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, I've gotten error messages about several packages that supposedly need to be installed.

Comment: You need to follow the above procedure or remove all packages and install them one by one.

Comment: The above command will auto resolved your all package dependencies.