# Unable to install NugetPackage due to Unity reversing Nuget changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nuget

Ok, I am desperate:
I am trying to access a MariaDB installation from C# under Unity3D using Rider2020.
After installing the MySqlConnector 1.1.0 (or 1.0.0 as well) via NuGet I can see the package has been added.
[image: NuGet display after installing MySqlConnector]

However when I try to use the "using" directive for it, the system can at first find it.

[image: Rider shows the using in regular color signaling that it knows "MySqlConnector"]

[image: The entry in the references is clearly visible]

But when I save the file, the entry is deleted from the references! And subsequently the buid fails.

[image: After "save" the entry disappears from the references]

I have been experimenting for 4(!) days now un/reinstalling both VS2019 and Rider. Without any result.
I have to note that this does not only concern this package but also MySql.
So it probably is not related to the package.
The removal only happens when I opened the source from the Unity3D editor. If I just use Rider to edit the source file, saving does not remove the reference. So it seems obvious that Unity is causing this.

I am aware of this StackOverflow question: [Nuget package installed but references not resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663511/nuget-package-installed-but-references-not-resolved)
but trying the approaches there did not solve my problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the Unity editor does not support NuGet. I used NuGetForUnity (on GitHub) instead - and it magically worked!