# Can not resolve reference 'Package' referenced by 'Project.Android', when updating a new package in an existing project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I am maintaining a NuGetPackage that act as barcode scanner in my new work, that gets rarely updated. So after I updated it, I generated a .nuspec, and built a pipeline for it in azure devops. After successfully generated a NuGetPackage, I integrated it in our existing application, then I get this error:

> Complete Error Message: Can not resolve reference 'NuGetPackage' referenced by 'Project.Android', referenced by 'Project.Android'. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for 'Reference', or remove the reference to 'Project.Android'

- Reinstalling, Uninstalling, Installing back the NuGetPackage
  reference: [Nuget package installed but references not resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663511/nuget-package-installed-but-references-not-resolved)
- Add All in Project.Android.csproj

reference: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4521

I tried various steps such as the following:

- Adding and removing *exclude="Build,Analyzers"* in .nuspec file
  `<dependency id="Sharpnado.Forms.HorizontalListView" version="1.8.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />`
- Made sure the similar dependencies of the NuGetPackage, .nuspec file and the Project.Android have the same version

I'm expecting the build should be successful and running, but to no avail it keeps saying that the package cannot be referenced. Any leads, suggested solution would be much appreciated. Thank you!